# Apache vhosts unable to connect

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I'm trying to configure my apache so that I can use myprojectname.dev for all my projects dynamically. However, no matter what I try, I keep getting errors. Unable to connect is what firefox says, however I have no idea what is wrong. I have followed several tutorials on how to do this and all result in the same thing.

I have added the domain I want to use to my hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1

Using the latest version of Apache and Ubuntu 18.04LTS. Sites file is enabled, vhosts mod is enabled. My browser also keeps redirecting to https for some reason. Pinging the domain confirms that it points to localhost. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my config file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/var/www">
    Options ExecCGI Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    UseCanonicalName off
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.dev
    ServerAlias *.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2+/Web
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have a Listen directive?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you mean by that? I'm really new to all this

Comment: My ports.conf states to listen at port 80

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen  You need to have a Listen directive in a conf file. not sure what ports.conf is. mine is in httpd.conf

Comment: Yea, that is set, when I go to localhost I also get the apache welcome page normally, so it is definitely there.

Comment: Try "apachectl configtest" and see if it complains about anything.

Comment: Everything seems fine, syntax ok

Comment: You might want to subscribe to the apache user'ss mailing list. They probably have move ideas. https://httpd.apache.org/userslist.html

Comment: I'll see what they know, thanks

Comment: Sorry should have been "You might want to subscribe to the apache user's mailing list. They probably have more ideas. "

Answer (score 0):

Is there any **firewall** rule set on the machine (iptables, firewalld)? Moreover, you may need to disable **SElinux**.
So you may need to disable both firewall and SELinux on your machine.

You say that your machine listens Port 80. Please try telnet to your local machine for Port 80 (both from machine itself, and also if possible from a machine shares the same network)

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 80
telnet <whatever_ip> 80
```

I think you will telnet successfuly from local. In that case please also try to get your website content from machine itself (by using machine's mozilla or commands like curl, wget by using 127.0.0.1 IP)

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer. Apparently Google owns the .dev tld and Chrome does not even check your configuration, just sends you straight to google.